# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am have a problem with the following `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token Error` after switching from an `input box` to `textarea`. This error occurs when trying to delete the text entered into the textarea after submitting it.

textarea:

```
<textarea name="chatter"></textarea>
```

Function call:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' 
 onClick='deletecmnt(this, '".$val['id']."', '".BASE_URL."');' 
  title='Delete Chatter'>X</a>;
```

delete function:

```
function deletecmnt(obj, cmt_id, baseurl){
    var lg_chk = loginchk();
    if(lg_chk){
        var object = $(obj).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
           // error: function(error){console.log("Error:");console.log(error);},
            url:baseurl+'deletechatter.php?id='+cmt_id,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(response){
                object.remove();
            }
        });
    }
    else
        location.href=baseurl;
}
```

Ok so inside Chrome I receive the error stated above but in Firefox I receive the following:

```
 SyntaxError: syntax error      

 deletecmnt(this,
```

However, I don't see anything wrong with it and it worked when I was using a input box. I even switched it back and it worked so what is it about the textarea that it does like? Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Here is what I got so far:

```
<a data-id='".$val['id']."' data-base-url='".BASE_URL."' href='javascript:void(0);' title='Delete Chatter'>x</a>

<script>$("a[title='Delete Chatter']").on('click', deletecmnt);</script>

function deletecmnt(obj, cmt_id, baseurl){
var lg_chk = loginchk();
if(lg_chk){
    var object = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
       // error: function(error){console.log("Error:");console.log(error);},
        url:baseurl+'deletechatter.php?id='+cmt_id,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){
            object.remove();
        }
    });
}
else
    location.href=baseurl;
```

}

Comment: It looks like you're using PHP. Please show the rendered output. I bet that will lead to the error...

Comment: ^^^^^ What Lee Taylor says. You'll see the problem immediately if you look at the HTML source instead of the PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are wrong:

```
onClick='deletecmnt(this, "'.$val['id'].'", "'.BASE_URL.'");'
```

Look how you open and close single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the apostrophe prematurely:

```
deletecmnt(this,
```

...becomes the entire `onclick`.  Since you are using jQuery, it makes a lot more sense to bind with it (even if you weren't, I would still suggest doing so with JS).

```
$("a[title='Delete Chatter']").on('click', deletecmnt);
```

You can update `deletecmnt` so that it references `this`, which would be the anchor.  Also, update the anchor to store the ID and BASE_URL as part of the DOM, possibly with:

```
<a data-id='".$val['id']."' data-base-url='".BASE_URL."'
```

Comment: I think I got everything else but I am not sure how reference this. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Inside of the `deletecmnt` function, just use `this` and it should be the anchor.  `var object = $(this).parent().parent()` for example

Comment: Can you please look at my code I added at the top because it is not firing now.

Comment: @ClaudeGrecea you need to get `cmt_id` and `base_url` from the anchor: `var cmt_id = $(this).data('id'); var base_url = $(this).data('base-url')`

Comment: Ok, I got it to sort of work but it won't delete in real time. I have to refresh the page. What do you think this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that `success` is being called?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25195/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-claude-grecea)